# Will the Thailand Elite Visa be valid if I renew my passport?

Tags: visas, usa, thailand, passport-renewals

I have a US passport, but it will expire in a couple years. I wanted to apply for the Thailand's [Elite Visa](https://www.thailandelite.net/) -- which spans from 5 years to 20 years, depending on the specific type. If I get the Elite Visa now, will it be valid for the entire duration it was originally meant for -- even after I inevitably renew my passport later?

Comment: Since the passport recommendation is that a passport should only be valid up to 10 years, I would suggest looking at an **official site** instead of an unofficial one that states that they won't accept membership applications after the 14th of September 20023.

Comment: Seems scammy as hell, but looks like it's actually a true visa. @MarkJohnson Even the [Thai embassy in Singapore sends people back to Thailand Elite](https://singapore.thaiembassy.org/en/page/elite-visa) for that visa. Note that they say the current offers will stop being accepted after 14/09/2023, but that new offers will be available from October. Hopefully those with the old memberships will continue to get (all) the services promised to them.

Answer (score 1):

The Thai Ministry of Foreign Affairs [tells us](https://www.mfa.go.th/en/page/frequently-asked-questions-faqs):

> #### If a Passport expires but still contains a Visa which is still valid, is it then possible to append an old Passport to a new one?
>
> No, but an applicant may request to record endorsements from the old Passport which still has a valid visa to the new e-Passport.  Therefore, the applicant can present the old passport which has a valid visa to foreign immigration together with the new e-Passport.

The phrasing is a bit weird, but as long as you can keep your old passport with the visa inside (consulates will usually give the passport back if there are any valid visas, with the passport itself invalidated, often by cutting a corner, but it's always better to emphasise that you need the passport back for the visas in your renewal application, if they need the old passport), you can present the visa in the old passport together with the new passport.

Since they are supposed to provide personalised fast track service and assistance at the airport (including affixing the visa sticker in your passport the first time), they should be able to assist with all that in any case. I certainly hope they do, given the price!